# how to store user details in session and pass to Spring REST controllers

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

We have login page where user will enter user credentials  and internally calling one more authenticate service where need to store this token and pass to all REST controllers.I tried configuring bean scope within this class and but getting below exception .we are using spring 5.x;

com.config.CustomAuthenticationProvider sessionScopedBean
 CustomAuthenticationProvider UserDetails !!!null
Jun 20, 2020 11:52:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.NullBean cannot be cast to com.utils.UserDetails

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
    private UserDetails userDetails;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String userName = authentication.getName();
        String passWord = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        Result response;
        try {
            response = CustomClient.authenticate(userName, passWord);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("system authentication failed");
        }
        if (response != null && response.getToken() != null) {

            //need to store this response.getToken() in session
            logger.info("Token: " + response.getToken());

            userDetails= new UserDetails();
                userDetails.setToken(response.getToken());


            logger.info("Authentication SUCCESS !!!");
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userName, passWord, Collections.emptyList());
        } else {
            logger.info("Authentication FAILED...");
            throw new BadCredentialsException("authentication failed");
        }
    }

   @Bean
    @Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public UserDetails sessionScopedBean() {
        logger.info(" UserDetails !!!"+userDetails);
        return userDetails;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> auth) {
        return auth.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to create session scoped `UserDetails` bean in the first place? You can already achieve it by doing the following:

```
@GetMapping("/abc")
public void getUserProfile(@AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails user ) {
...
}
```

or

```
    @GetMapping("/abc")
    public void getUserProfile() {
        SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        UserDetails user = (UserDetails) securityContext.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    }
```

**Note:**

Behind the scene, spring uses `HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository` to store your `SecurityContext` in http session and restore it back on every request

**And the Updated CustomAuthenticationProvider**

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String userName = authentication.getName();
        String passWord = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        Result response;
        try {
            response = CustomClient.authenticate(userName, passWord);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("system authentication failed");
        }
        if (response != null && response.getToken() != null) {

            //need to store this response.getToken() in session
            logger.info("Token: " + response.getToken());

            UserDetails userDetails= new UserDetails();
            userDetails.setToken(response.getToken());


            logger.info("Authentication SUCCESS !!!");
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, passWord, Collections.emptyList());
        } else {
            logger.info("Authentication FAILED...");
            throw new BadCredentialsException("authentication failed");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> auth) {
        return auth.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can not create Bean like your example. @Bean annotation is processed when application context is starting. UserDetails will be null so it can not be created.

You are creating UserDetails after applacation context is up.

Do you really want to keep session if that's case

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public UserDetails userDetails() {
        return new UserDetails();
    }

}


@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
    @Autowired
    private UserDetails userDetails;
    
}
```

You can inject by Autowire or constructor injection

Don't instantiate it manually just inject it and use in method like below

```
userDetails.setToken(response.getToken());
```

Comment: SpringSecurityContextHolder keeps data for you if you want to receive it